# $f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*) \Rightarrow \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x^*) \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, maxima-minima

My textbook, *Algorithms for Optimization*, by Kochenderfer and Wheeler, says the following:

> A point can also be at a local minimum if it has a zero derivative and the second derivative is merely nonnegative:
>
> 1. $f'(x^∗) = 0$, the *first-order necessary condition* (FONC)
> 2. $f''(x^∗) \ge 0$, the *second-order necessary condition* (SONC)
>
> These conditions are referred to as necessary because all local minima obey these two rules. Unfortunately, not all points with a zero derivative and a zero second derivative are local minima, as demonstrated in figure 1.7.
>
> The first necessary condition can be derived using the Taylor expansion about our candidate point $x^*$:
>
> $$f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$$
> $$f(x^∗ − h) = f(x^∗) − hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$$
> $$f(x^∗ + h) \ge f(x^∗) \Rightarrow hf'(x^∗) \ge 0$$
> $$f(x^∗ − h) \ge f(x^∗) \Rightarrow hf'(x^∗) \le 0$$
> $$\Rightarrow f'(x^∗)=0$$
>
> The second-order necessary condition can also be obtained from the Taylor expansion:
>
> $$f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + \underbrace{hf'(x^∗)}_{\text{$=0$}} + \dfrac{h^2}{2} f''(x^∗) + O(h^3)$$
>
> We know that the first-order necessary condition must apply:
>
> $$f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*) \Rightarrow \dfrac{h^2}{2} f''(x^*) \ge 0$$
>
> since $h > 0$. It follows that $f''(x^*) \ge 0$ must hold for $x^*$ to be at a local minimum.

I don't see how $f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*) \Rightarrow \dfrac{h^2}{2} f''(x^*) \ge 0$ is true? For instance, take the case of a positive and increasing function just after its inflection point. It would be true that $f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*)$ for $h > 0$, and it would also be true that $f'(x^*) > 0$. However, it would not be true that $f''(x^*) \ge 0$, since the function at this point (since it is just after its inflection point) is concave down, meaning that $f''(x^*) < 0$.

So how can it be said that $f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*) \Rightarrow \dfrac{h^2}{2} f''(x^*) \ge 0$? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Would a function such as you describe *also* satisfy $f'(x^*) = 0$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No, it would not. Hmm, the way it was written might be what confused me. So the textbook is saying that, if $f(x^* + h) \ge f(x^*)$ *and* $f'(x^*) = 0$, then $\dfrac{h^2}{2} f''(x^*) \ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, I think those sentences are poorly punctuated.  But basically, I think the textbook is using the FONC within the proof of the SONC.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(x^*) = 0$
$$f(x^* + h ) \ge f(x^*) \implies \frac{h^2f''(x^*)}{2} + O(h^3) \ge  0$$

By the defintion of $O(h^3)$ we have

$$\frac{h^2f''(x^*)}{2} + Mh^3 \ge  0$$

for some $M>0$.

This means $$f''(x^*) \ge -2Mh$$
for arbitrarily small $h$. This means $f''(x^*) \ge 0$

Comment: Ahh, that's an interesting way to phrase it.

Comment: Usually textbooks assume its quite clear from the initial inequality. I used to struggle with doing analysis with big Os since I was more used to epsilon-delta so used to do a lot of arguments like this before being comfortable reading texts that use Os.

Comment: So this essentially comes down to the fact that we can make the $h$ arbitrarily small. This means that, despite the fact that the right-hand side term is negative, $f''(x^*)$ must be $\ge 0$. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes precisely because if we assume $f''(x^*) = -1$ for example we can find an $h$ small enough to show that this is not true. We can do the same for all negative numbers, hence showing it must be $\ge 0$